About multiple weights linear regression function
I have a question that I dont understand. Lets assume our data is velocity and Re. We know that based on one velocity, we can calculate one Re (one velocity, one Re. One velocity, two Re is not possible). Lets say our data is u1=1, Re=1, u2=2, Re=2.3, u3=3, Re=2.5. We can simply assume the regression function as Re = wx + b, assume w and b can be calculated by machine learning. After we have w and b, we can predict Re for any value of u.
But if we assume the regression function as Re=w1x1 + w2x2 + b, also lets assume w1 w2 and b can be calculated by machine learning. Then it can be seen that Re is related with two x (x1 and x2), which means its related with two velocities. This is not physical.
I dont quite understand this.
I expect an answer. Thanks.

The key point here is that the choice of regression function should be guided by the underlying physical or real-world relationships between the variables.
In your first example, you have a single independent variable (velocity, u) and a single dependent variable (Re). You’re assuming a linear relationship between them, which can be represented as Re = wx + b. This is a simple linear regression model, and it’s a reasonable choice if you expect a linear relationship between velocity and Re.
In your second example, you’re considering a multiple linear regression model: Re = w1x1 + w2x2 + b. This model assumes that Re depends on two independent variables (x1 and x2). If x1 and x2 represent different physical quantities (say, velocity and temperature), this model could make sense. However, if x1 and x2 both represent velocity, then this model would indeed be unphysical, as you’ve noted. In reality, Re cannot depend on two different values of velocity at the same time.
So, the choice of regression model should be based on your understanding of the underlying physical processes. If you know that Re depends on velocity in a one-to-one manner, then a simple linear regression model is appropriate. If Re depends on multiple independent variables, then a multiple linear regression model might be more suitable. But in any case, the model should reflect the actual physical relationships between the variables.

The most common process that happens behind the hood in a regression model is that, it selects the weights that minimize the RSS(Residual sum of square) for given X and Y variables and the relationship you choose to have between them. If we falsely assume the relationship between X and Y(that Y depend on two X values), what happen is that we get weights that minimizes the RSS in the current context. That's about it. Nothing more to it or less.
So, what you get is considered the most appropriate approximation for the current number of data points and the relationship that you provided to train the Model, even though it does not  represent the actual relationship.
